# Term for most degenerate tree with two children on every inner node

Tags: graphs, terminology, trees

I'm looking for the name of a binary tree which is almost degenerate: at least one child of every interior node in the tree is a leaf.

[image]

(Image from Penn State course STAT 557, *Data Mining*, [lesson 10](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat557/node/83).)

Comment: If all nodes have degree 2 then what you get is a disjoint union of *cycles*, rather than a binary tree.

Comment: Why "almost" degenerated?

Comment: "almost" degenerated because all nodes have degree 2, except the leave nodes which have degree 0.

Comment: The leaves of the tree in your image have degree one, *not* degree zero.

Comment: @Juho Why they have degree one ? Yet they have 0 children...

Comment: If we interpret the tree as an undirected graph, then the degree of a vertex $v$ is the number of vertices adjacent to $v$. So every leaf has degree 1. Perhaps we would agree if we looked at the tree as a directed graph. Then, one could say the out-degree of the leaf is 0 (but the in-degree is 1).

Comment: Remember to upvote those answers you liked, and accept the one that helped you most.

Answer (score 3):

This *is* a binary tree, when by a binary tree we mean a tree where each vertex has at most 2 children. In other words, you have a tree of maximum degree 3. Also, generally a tree that has a dominating path is a *caterpillar*.

Comment: Thanks juho. i'm looking for a name describing a tree where all inner nodes have two children.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this type of tree called a *comb*. But this isn't such a widespread term that you can use it without defining it.

Technically, a nested data structure where every node has one child that's a leaf, with the list always on the same side, is a *list*. When the last node has two leaves the one that's not on the usual leaf side is not a special “null” marker, it's an *improper list*. But this terminology works for data structures, it sounds strange when applied to a decision tree.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. There isn't a particular name for such a tree ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean a rooted tree for which all interior nodes have two children?

These are called *extended* binary trees, and the one you have would be the extended binary tree with maximum height among all such with $n$ nodes.